# what's wrong in the circuit given below?

Tags: circuit-analysis, short-circuit

[image]

well is there something wrong in the ciruit or it will work perfectly by this method?

Comment: Nothing wrong if you have people that live there wanting to become the next candidates for the Darwin Awards, the ultimate contest for gene pool reduction.  Only idiots need apply.

Comment: It isn't impedance matched.

Comment: You have line voltage (220VAC) lying in the open uninsulated.  Anyone can touch it and kill themselves.  If you insulate it with tape, you will convert it from an electrocution hazard to a fire hazard.  The connections are lousy, and can spark or get hot enough to set the insulating material on fire.

Comment: Didn't take the time to minimize loop area, poor EMC...

Comment: Thislike systems should not be very common in modern industrialized countries due the strict requlations. No insurace pays if someone dies or the house get burned after doing or handling this. But thislike systems live where people have  worse everyday problems than this. Who cares a couple of uninsulated wires, when any time someone can come and kill you only to get your money, phone and cloths.

Comment: Yeah, any random bastard could come in and kill you at any time.  Just make it easier on him and kill yourself before hand with this handy, dandy combination electrocution and incineration device.

Comment: This looks like something i would likely find in the home of my ex girlfriend in the Philippines. Everything is wrong with this configuration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now, how could this kill you?

- Touch the exposed live copper, obviously. But this isn't likely to happen, I mean anyone seeing this would steer clear. Unless, well, it is next to a bed, so if you roll in your sleep and touch it...

IMO the most interesting things will happen when someone pulls on a USB cable, or the phone being charged falls to the floor and pulls the cable.

- This twists the entire contraption, and makes wires touch. Who wants to bet the installation inside that building has working fuses or circuit breakers? Let's be serious here, someone probably wrapped aluminium foil around the fuses already. The building burns down.
- This twists the entire contraption,and it touches the metallic bed frame. Whoever is leaning on the bed at that time gets a free defibrillation.
- Someone pulls on the USB cable, only one white wire disengages from the socket, and it makes contact with the guy sleeping on the bed.
- You bring a girl home and the... ahem... shaking of the bed loosens the mess... Surprised by the shock, she bites off whatever was in her mouth at the time...
- I am quite disappointed that one of the appliances isn't an electric heater. This, combined with the bad contacts (no spring forces) thus high contact resistance, means... the building burns down.

But there is worse on the internets.

[image]

Compared to this nightmare, your contraption could be considered safe! I mean, it has insulation and everything.

Bonus: you actually have to know what you're doing to assemble this horror and still be alive to take the picture afterwards...

Comment: Now I want to cry.

Comment: I'm a landlord. I have tenants. I have seen things. The largest load, usually an electric space heater, shall *always* be plugged at the end of a huge chain of power strips. This is why, when I renovate, I make sure to put more than enough outlets, everywhere I can.

Comment: okay i died laughing after reading this answer. maybe, now i am saved from getting burnt alive.

Comment: LOL, yeah. Worst thing I ever saw when renovating was an old installation entirely done with flexible wires. This is forbidden by code, for good reason: the tiny strands will oxidize and corrode much quicker than solid core wire... and stranded wire does not work well with screw terminals. Some of the outlets in the walls only had a few strands left making contact. Huge fire hazard.

Comment: @peufeu -- stranded wire is OK by Code at least in the US actually (and sometimes preferred in conduit jobs) -- it just has to be installed correctly with devices rated for stranded wire...(then again,  stranded THHN is seven-strand stuff, not finely stranded wire).  You can never have too many receptacles though!

Comment: It's forbidden in-wall by french residential code (don't know about industrial). In the case I saw, the finely stranded wires were pretty corroded... and the old outlets had screw terminals without push plates, the kind of terminals where the end of the screw compresses the wire directly, without a pressure plate, and this doesn't work bare with stranded wires... the strands break or come out...

Comment: @TomCarpenter  Judging from the position of the rocker switch, I don't think he was stupid enough [or brave enough, or drunk enough] to energize the circuit.

Comment: Wouldn't bet on the switch cutting both live and neutral...

Answer (score 4):

If you ignore the exceedingly high probability of **death** by electrocution, or the risk of **death** in the ensuing fire...

...the wires are the wrong colour.

Beyond that, it will certainly do *something*.

---

I forget, did I mention **death**?

Comment: will the circuit work fine?

Comment: @SaadAnwar if by "work" you mean "kill you or burn your house down", then yes, it will certainly do that.

Answer (score 2):

It's lethal - don't do it!

You could seriously injure someone else, not just yourself.

Buy a proper plugblock.

Comment: will the circuit work fine?

Comment: If you sit in a bath with the mains live going through it, holding a light bulb connected to mains neutral, the circuit will work. But you will be dead so it doesn't matter if the circuit works. **The answer is no.**

Answer (score 1):

Technically there is no fault in this circuit. But it is lethal (Since it is exposed and can cause damage to anyone).

Furthermore, this is not stable, a single movement and the wires are shorted together, a bang will occur and infinite energy would be generated (Current will go up).